# How to access my codeigniter folder in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, lamp

I have deployed my codeigniter folder into /var/www/html . But when i am trying to access it using http://localhost/CodeIgniter/ this is showing Server error

500

The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/CodeIgniter/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. But when i am creting a new folder into /var/www/html/ and creating a hello.php file in it and that is working fine.

Comment: How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to give special permissions to Codeigniter folder.

```
$ sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/Codeigniter
```

Also, keep a backup of the .htaccess file then remove it from the Codeigniter folder.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to verify folder/files permission like previous answer with command `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/Codeigniter` and for file 644 as permissions -R is for recursively.

2) Look for your .htaccess file and if you have enabled mod_rewrite on apache, if no enabled open terminal and `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

3) Look for owner permission in `/var/www/html/Codeigniter` if you are locally set it to your own user, else set it to `www-data`

Hope it will help